# Woocommerce credit card payment issues

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

when a customer places an order via credit card it auto changes from pending to processing, is there a specific hook so I can keep it on pending when a new order is placed. so far COD works fine new order goes as pending

Current hooks I use for COD when a new order is placed instead of "processing" it sets to pending

```
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'rename_order_statuses', 20, 1 );
function rename_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {

    $order_statuses['wc-pending']    = _x( 'Pending', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );

    return $order_statuses;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cod_process_payment_order_status', 'default_cod_payment_order_status', 10 );
function default_cod_payment_order_status( $order_status ) {
    return 'pending';
}
```

but the credit card purchases auto changed pending processing
can someone show me the hook for this too if possible thanks?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'wc_payment_update_order_status', 10, 2 );

function wc_payment_update_order_status( $order_status, $order_id ) {

 return 'pending'; 

}
```